# An Incomplete Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, calculation-puzzle, grid-deduction, sudoku

I'm sorry to offload some of my work as the puzzle creator on to you solvers. (No, I'm not.) At least there's only one clue missing, right? *EDIT: When the puzzle is ready to be solved, there will be six regions with clues instead of five, and any number of unclued regions. Apologies to Eric Tressler.*

Complete the puzzle, and then complete the puzzle.

Check mark goes to one who completes the puzzle correctly **with a full explanation**.

[image: the grid; i.stack.imgur.com/cXMz0.png]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To begin with,

> Each pair is either {2,6} or {3,5}. The partitions of 8 into five parts, no four equal: 11123, 11222. The upper zigzag cannot be 11222, because then a 3 has to go in the upper cell of the lower zigzag and it can't be completed.

Continuing,

> This lets us complete the lower zigzag, the upper zigzag, and then the pair on the left. The 3-part piece has no 1s, and at most one 2. {2,3,3} is the only solution. This means the upper pair cannot be {3,5}, but is instead {2,6}, and a 2 is already blocking the right cell. We can place the final 1 uniquely in the lower right, as the other five have been placed.

This gets us here:

> [image]

---

The new region

> has to be a pair touching one the upper right cells with "3" as an option, because an 8+ made out of the remaining numbers must be a {3,5}. We can rule out any regions strictly contained in the upper-right 2 by 2 block, because

these are both valid:

> [image]

Since

> the cells below that 2 by 2 block only have {4,6} as options and not {3,5}, we can rule those out also.

We have ruled out these regions:

> [image]

If we try the lower of the remaining regions, we get:

> [image] stuck.

So we are left with the upper one, for:

> [image]

The new region

> is an 8+, and it is easy to complete the puzzle with this region.

Comment: Mea culpa on the question being unclear; I've updated it now. My intention was that the missing piece is one final clued region to go with the current five (leaving any number of regions unclued, like the single-cell area)

Comment: I've edited out the old (incorrect) answer, as the semi-detailed correct answer is long enough on its own.